# Principal Component Analysis: Order of components AFTER transformation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

I am using the `PCA` class from `sklearn.decomposition` to reduce the dimensionality of the feature space in order to plot that feature space.

I wondering the following: After applying the `fit` and `transform` method of the `PCA` class, I am getting back an array `X_transformed` of shape `(n_samples, n_components)` as stated in the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.PCA.transform). Is the order of columns of `X_transformed` sorted by the amount of explained variance? In the documentation it says that `PCA.components_` is sorted by explained variance, so I am assuming that the columns of `X_transformed` are as well, but please correct me if I am wrong.

Little example:

```py
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA


pca = PCA()
pca.fit(X) # X is an array containing my original features. X.shape=(n_samples, n_features)
X_transformed = pca.transfom(X) # X_transformed.shape=(n_samples, n_components). Are X_transformed's columns sorted by explained variance?
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm maybe just got an idea to test that

```py
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import numpy as np


pca_2 = PCA(n_components=2)
X_transformed_2 = pca_2.fit_transform(X)
# X_transformed_2 hold two components with most variance explained

pca_10 = PCA(n_components=10)
X_transformed_10 = pca_10.fit_transform(X)
# X_transformed_10 hold 10 components with most variance explained


# Hypothesis: If the first 2 components in X_transformed_10 are ordered by explained variance, it's first 2 columns should equal X_transformed_2
np.array_equal(X_transformed_2, X_transformed_10[:, 2]) ## returns True
```